# What is this sticky outy bit called?

Tags: building-design, terminology

We have a bit of wall sticking out of a flat wall

```
           ____
__________|    |_______________
```

I have always called it the sticky outy bit of the wall and everyone knew what I meant.  My boss told me I need to find out the proper name for a bit of wall that sticks out because it is a point of reference in a document.  I can't keep on calling it the sticky-outy bit that I've called it for the last 3 years.

I've been looking at https://www.house-design-coffee.com/architectural-dictionary.html.  There is the word architrave but it is for a horizontal section below the roof.

There is also pilaster but all the examples I've seen have fancy decorations on it.  A sort of fake column.  Can it be called a pilaster if there are no decorations?

The other alternative is protrusion - can this be used for something that sticks out from ceiling to floor or just a bit of wall.

**Edit**

To answer @Fred's query - it is about 1ft (30cm wide) and about 4" (10cm) deep.  It stretches from ceiling to floor.  I've got no idea what it is for.  Sorry, I cannot supply a photograph - it is in one of those restricted areas where cameras aren't allowed.

Comment: Pillar or buttress come to mind.

Comment: you could call it a `rib`

Comment: Some questions. Is it on an internal or external wall? What are the dimensions? What is it being used for, or what can it be used for? Could you add a photograph of it?

Comment: Support beam protrusion.

Comment: A rectangular protruberance =D

Comment: @SolarMike - I did consider buttress but I always visualize a buttress as triangular protrusion.

Comment: Is it part of a chimney?

Comment: @SolarMike it isn't part of a chimney - this is on the 3rd floor of a 5 storey building which doesn't have chimneys.  I've never been upstairs - it is an admin area and I can't figure out where it is relative to the downstairs offices.

Comment: Well, as your image is so poor, anything is a valid guess. Even if we suggest the correct answer, you won’t know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If both the wall and the bump-out are made of masonry/bricks, it is usually called a pilaster, which was built integrally with the wall.

If the bump-out is concrete, it is called a column.

Both have structural significance in carrying gravity loads and resisting lateral loads.

However, if it is made of drywall material, then it is usually a decorative column, or to hide the steel column behind.

Note, you can check whether there is a horizontal beam, at the upper end, lays perpendicular to the bump-out to determine if this is a structural column, or decorative protrusion.

Comment: Bump-out is the first thing that came to mind as an all-encompassing term. Other terms are related to purpose, which we don't know.

Comment: I had a look a pictures of pilasters.  Finally found one that does not have any decoration which looks like my sticky outy bit.